# Android rotate viewgroup with childs

Tags: java, android

i have some serious problems understanding some basics of the android view hierarchy.
I have a `ViewGroup` that is bigger than the screen and overlaps the screen on all for sides. This `ViewGroup` has some `ChildViews/SubViews`, e.g. `Buttons`. Now, i want to rotate the entire `ViewGroup` with its SubViews about the middle point.

In iOS I simple can take a `UIView`, put some subviews on it and make an affine transform of the superview. With that, the super view and all its subviews rotate about the middle point.

Is there a similar way in Android?

I draw a little [image](http://s1.directupload.net/images/130425/xcfncook.png) to show you my problem ;-)

Comment: I think i found a solution. `ViewGroup` is a sublass of `View`and `View` has a method `setRotation(float angle)`. I hope this solves my problem. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Found a good example on this page. [link](http://www.41post.com/4806/programming/android-how-to-rotate-a-view-element). Explains how to rotate a ViewGroup.

Comment: Your solution only work on API >= 11. setRotation() Was introduced in api 11. If you want to support lower api you have to explicitly handle draw() and rotate the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a good example on this [page](http://www.41post.com/4806/programming/android-how-to-rotate-a-view-element). Explains how to rotate a entire `ViewGroup` and its contents.